# File Download UIWebView to UITableView

Tags: ios, xcode, uitableview, uiwebview, download

i managed to make a downloader with UIWebView. what i want to do is, when the download starts, 
it should start in a different viewcontroller say tableView.

I have a tabbar controller in which last tab is downloads, i want my download to show there, including progress bar in tableViewCell.

If i pass the grabbed url to tableView, and start download from there, its not working. 
Sorry if i am not making it clear.. cause i am confused myself.

Regards,

Malhaar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try [this](http://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/hcdownload) one, quite good. Works background as well.